# Why am i only seeing 1 record not 2 records?

Tags: aws-appsync, resolver

I am only seeing 1 record when there are 2.

The Resolver Response mapping section is
    $utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0])

I figured out if I change:

```
    $utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0])
```

to:

```
    $utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][1])
```

I get the second record but not the first?

```
Resolver for Query.getdpackByind_subcat, Request mapping template
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "select * from dpack WHERE ind = '$ctx.args.ind' AND subcat = 
         '$ctx.args.subcat'"
    ]
}

Resolver for Query.getdpackByind_subcat, Response mapping template
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end
$utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0])
```

Got this information from:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds- 
resolvers.html the Query.getPet Resolvers

In the CloudWatch log at the bottom of the Response mapping section
,indicated by the `_____->`, 2 records are returned. However, only 1 was 
Transformed, indicated by the `*******>`, why? 

"____>records\":[[{\"stringValue\"
:\"bb973271-0091-4b0e-84c4-f1b50fe6517e\"}, 
{\"stringValue\":\"Government\"},{\"stringValue\":\"Police 
Surveillance\"},{\"stringValue\":\"20 pixs\"},{\"longValue\":700}, 
{\"stringValue\":\"service 20 pixs\"},{\"blobValue\":\"Yi5qcGc=\"}], 
[{\"stringValue\":\"d219d0f8-aef7-4a17-bcaf-85504f56494a\"}, 
{\"stringValue\":\"Government\"},{\"stringValue\":\"Police 
Surveillance\"},{\"stringValue\":\"15 picks\"},{\"longValue\":500}, 
{\"stringValue\":\"service 15 picks\"}, 
{\"blobValue\":\"YS5qcGc=\"}]]}]}","stash": {},"outErrors": []},

 *******>"transformedTemplate": "\n{\"pack_id\"
 :\"bb973271-0091-4b0e-84c4- 
 f1b50fe6517e\",\"price\":700,\"subcat\":\"Police 
 Surveillance\",\"pack_title\":\"service 20 
 pixs\",\"ind\":\"Government\",\"content\":\"20 
 pixs\",\"picture\":\"Yi5qcGc=\"}"
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but it is unlikely that anybody is going to read through your whole question to try and figure out what you are doing. Is there some way you can shorten your question to focus on the specific problem or section of code that is causing you difficulty? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you share more about your data source? Is it DynamoDB, by chance?

Comment: Aurora via appsync

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query result is a list.

Thus `$utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0])`
 corresponds to the first item of the list so only one item is returned.

To return the whole list, you should remove the second array index. Look at the response mapping template for `Query.listPet` in the Appsync RDS Tutorial for an example.

[Tutorial: Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html#run-queries)